# Rendering template for newform and code behind

Tags: asp.net, forms, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, code-behind

I'm trying to create a rendering template for my forms which need complex validations treatments.
the rendering template is working fine wwith :

```xml
<XmlDocuments>
    <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
        <FormTemplates xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
            <Display>ListForm</Display>
            <Edit>ChaisTemplate</Edit>
            <New>ChaisTemplate</New>
        </FormTemplates>
    </XmlDocument>          
</XmlDocuments>
```

and with my ascx :

```
<%@ Control AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ChaisTemplate.ascx.cs" 
Inherits="TransactionsFormsTemplates.ControlTemplates.ChaisTemplate, TransactionsFormsTemplates"
    Language="C#"  %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
    Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="ToolBar" Src="~/_controltemplates/ToolBar.ascx" %>
<%PageLoad(this, null);%>
<SharePoint:RenderingTemplate ID="ChaisTemplate" runat="server">

.....
```

but I can't have any control mappings in my code behind (in the webapp bin with cas policies, and it's correctly deployed)
this :

```
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="test"></asp:TextBox>
```

is null when it comes to :

```
 public partial class ChaisTemplate : System.Web.UI.UserControl 
{
    protected TextBox test;
```

so everytime I call test.Text on functions, I get a nullreferenceexception, because test is never mapped to my ascx textbox. why ? 
plus, the PageLoad is never called like in classic asp.net pages, even with <%PageLoad(this, null);%> at the beginning. 
however every event works :

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="button" OnClick="button_OnClick"/>
```

this will actually call button_OnClick in my code behind. But all my properties are null because not mapped.

did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'v been doing it like this. Take this as an example RenderingTemplate:

```
<SharePoint:RenderingTemplate ID="ParentItemsListView" runat="server">
    <Template>
        <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
            <tr><td nowrap class="UserGenericHeader"><asp:Label ID="lblParentItems" runat="server" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><SharePoint:ListViewByQuery ID="listViewByQuery" runat="server" /><br /></td></tr>
        </table>
    </Template>
</SharePoint:RenderingTemplate>
```

Then in Render event i can reference these controls like this:

```
    [SharePointPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, ObjectModel = true)]
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        if (this.Visible)
        {
            Label lblParentItems = this.TemplateContainer.FindControlRecursive<Label>("lblParentItems");
            lblParentItems.Text = "Pievienotie " + this.ChildList.Title;

            ListViewByQuery listView = TemplateContainer.FindControlRecursive<ListViewByQuery>("listViewByQuery");
            listView.List = this.ChildList;
            ...
            base.Render(output);
        }
   }
```

Ahh, yes, i use a handy extension function

```
public static T FindControlRecursive<T>(this Control parentControl, string id) where T : Control
{
    T ctrl = default(T);

    if ((parentControl is T) && (parentControl.ID == id))
        return (T)parentControl;

    foreach (Control c in parentControl.Controls)
    {
        ctrl = c.FindControlRecursive<T>(id);

        if (ctrl != null)
            break;
    }
    return ctrl;
}
```

However i had an issue where i inherited from `SaveButton` that i couldn't reference a control. In that case i changed so that i inherit from `FormControl` and i could find my control under `this.Controls`.

Also note that you cannot reference controls up until OnLoad event has executed (i.e if you're in OnLoad function, call `base.OnLoad(e)` before referencing controls.

Why is it so? I guess because it's not like you are having a template and then code behind (working with the same class/object), but it's more like you are rendering that ascx template in a different class/object file.